# Unable to get FlowHandlerMapping working in Spring Webflow

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm using SWF 2.1 with Spring 2.5.6. and am trying to get the default mapping strategy for 2.1 to work. I had previously been using the mapping strategy that was the 1.0 default (whereby the flow id was retrieved from the request parameters)

In spring MVC configuration, I'm using the simpleUrlMapping strategy (order = 1) and have declared the SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
```

SWF configuration:

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean><!--     

Launches new flow executions and resumes existing executions. -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="5" max-execution-snapshots="80"/>
</webflow:flow-executor>


<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<!-- 

Creates the registry of flow definitions for this application -->
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows"> 
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>

<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" development="true"/>

<bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref local="beanNameViewResolver"/>
            <ref local="internalResourceViewResolver"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Maps request paths to flows in the flowRegistry;
     e.g. a path of /hotels/booking looks for a flow with id "hotels/booking" -->       
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping"  p:order="0">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</bean>
```

Here is the directory structure in the web folder:

```
/WEB-INF/flows/flow1-name/flow1-flow.xml
/WEB-INF/flows/flow2-name/flow2-flow.xml
/WEB-INF/flows/flow3-name/flow3-flow.xml
```

I have been trying to access the flows by going to

```
http://www.appdomain.com/flow1-name
```

the mapping does not work and I get a 404.

Also, how should I name subflows and where should I put them? I would like to be able to access the subflows from more than one top-level flow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your servlet mapping in web.xml looks like but `http://www.appdomain.com/flow1-name` doesn't seem to include the name of your webapp and possibly the name of your servlet mapping. Check if the DispatcherServlet is getting reached at all. You can do that by enabling the org.springframework.web and org.springframework.webflow logging categories and looking for the output.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. The servlet mapping in web.xml is working. If I change the URL to one that is mapped to a normal MVC controller, it works fine.